# Powershell and Winforms - Encoding to Base64 and supplying the result to a TextBox control is extremely slow

Tags: powershell, performance, winforms

I am working on a small Winforms GUI Powershell Script that takes an input file, encodes to Base64, and then spits out the string into a standard `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

Here's the form for demonstration purposes:

[image: Form]

Unfortunately when I try this on files that are above 400-800kb in size, the application hangs and takes forever to populate the result.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$SelectedFileChanged = {

    if ($CBOXLoadedFiles.SelectedIndex -eq 0) {
        return
    }

    $P = $FilesCollection[$CBOXLoadedFiles.SelectedIndex].Filepath
    $B64String = [System.convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content -LiteralPath $P -AsByteStream -Raw))
    $TXTBOXBase64String.Text = $B64String
}
```

Now, if I try the same thing - but instead of populating the TextBox with the result I just simply write it to a file using `Out-File` - the operation completes almost instantly! This leads me to believe that the bottleneck is actually writing to the textbox in my GUI.

But this is unacceptable. There has to be a way to optimize things somehow so this doesn't take forever.

I could really use some help here. Any recommendations are highly appreciated!

Comment: Use a RichTextBox. -- You can probably have a similar *effect* in a multiline TextBox if you set `WordWrap = false`

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally worked. Unfortunately now I'm struggling to get a right click menu with `Copy`. Apparently the rich text box doesn't have a default context menu.

Comment: No, but you can use a standard ContextMenuStrip with a MenuItem that just calls the RTB's `Copy()` method. Anyway, also test a TextBox setup as described.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11276778/7571258) suggests to disable wordwrap.  Of course you don't want to show everything as single line, so pass `[Base64FormattingOptions]::InsertLineBreaks` as 2nd argument for `ToBase64String()`.

Comment: @zett42 A multiline TextBox with `WordWrap = false` shows multiline content. It just doesn't search for *words* to *wrap*. -- Maybe you don't want to have line breaks in a base64 that needs to be copied.

Comment: @Jimi Yes it still wraps text that doesn't fit its width by default, which is equally as slow as wordwrap. This can be preventd by setting `$textbox.ScrollBars = 'Both'`. The base64 of a 16 MB file takes about 3 s to display in the textbox on my machine.

Comment: @zett42 With or without scrollbars the text is wrapped. What slows it down is searching for words. A standard TextBox with just `WordWrap = false` (as I suggested in my very first comment) shows a ~100MB file (not the string length, the original file length in bytes, the string length is `121037296` chars) in `1.23` seconds in a test machine (including the load and conversion procedures).